# Create file from Uri return empty file

Tags: android, file, fileoutputstream

I am trying to read a file from Uri.
Reading is successfully but the return file is empty(android studio mark it as {File@66fgf}"" ) without any other data.
I have the Read and write to external storage permissions.
total reads 221688 bytes.
What i did wrong?

```
public static File getFile(Context context, Uri uri) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "TEMP" + File.separator, "_" + uri.getLastPathSegment());
    file.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file, false);
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    int len = 0;
    int total = 0;
    while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
        total += len;
    }
    fileOutputStream.close();
    inputStream.close();
    return file;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: try fileOutputStream.flush() before fileOutputStream.close()

Comment: I did it from the first try but without success.